# I need to save an html file so it can be used in another window

Tags: javascript, html, button, window, cross-domain

I have a form with 5 inputs in a file called upload.html. with localstorage, i was able to get the input values and utilize them in another file called result.html which was empty initially.

now, i want to save the updated window result.html and summon it at the click of a button which is in upload.html. How exactly do I do this

Comment: `and summon it at the click of a button` - Can you explain this part? Do you want to open a new window, an iframe within `upload.html`, or something else? What does `summon` mean? Also, when you say `i want to save the updated window result.html` - save it how? Permanently, on your computer, so that every time you open it, you see the values you saved previously?

Comment: there is a button in upload.html which says check result. what I want is that, if the button is clicked, it brings out the updated window result.html

Comment: Can you post the contents of `result.html`? Or is that file entirely empty, without any HTML elements?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `localStorage.setItem` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#examples) to save the values from `result.html`

Comment: I don't understand. please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

One way you can handle this is like this.

If your `results.html` is an entirely empty file, and it serves no other purpose, other than to store the results received from your form, you could avoid having it at all, and just make it through your JS code.

Some notes before we continue with the code:

- I'm ignoring the HTML part of your upload.html, and just posting the relevant JavaScript
- I'm assuming that your inputs are within a form, which has a `subimit` type button
- I am also assuming that your inputs are of the type text, number, password, or email, and that you are not using checkboxes, radio buttons, select elements, textareas, etc. I am making this assumption, for simplicity
- in order to avoid chasing down labels, and to avoid checking how and if they are paired with your inputs, I'm suggesting that your inputs contain a `data-info` attribute. The contents of that attribute can be any kind of text which explains the input - you can even repeat the question there, though that's not really advisable
- because I'm using `showSaveFilePicker`, opening of the `Save As` file dialogue will only work in [some of the browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showOpenFilePicker#browser_compatibility), and it will not work on mobile devices.

If you are comfortable with these assumptions, and they work for you, read on.

```
const myBtn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

myBtn.onclick = async (e) => {
    const options = {
        types: [
            {
                description: "Results",
                accept: {
                    "text/html": [".html"],
                },
            },
        ],
    };

    const handle = await window.showSaveFilePicker(options);
    const writable = await handle.createWritable();

    // we don't want to submit the form
    e.preventDefault();

    // let's get the inputs and their values
    let myInputs = document.querySelectorAll("#myForm input");

    // dummy results.html + table included, as it was asked in the comment
    let myHtml = '<html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf8"><title>Results</title></head><body><table><thead><tr><th>#</th><th>Question</th><th>Answer</th></thead><tbody>';

    // did we find any inputs within our form?
    if(myInputs.length > 0) {
        // to mark our rows
        let counter = 0;
        for(let i = 0; i < myInputs.length; i++) {
            counter++;

            let inpVal = myInputs[i].value;
            let inpInfo = myInputs[i].getAttribute('data-info');
            
            // building the rows
            let tempStr = '<tr><td>` + counter + '</td><td><strong>' + inpInfo + '</strong></td><td>' + inpVal + '</td></tr>';

            myHtml += tempStr;
        }
    }

    myHtml += '</tbody></table></body></html>';

    await writable.write(myHtml);
    await writable.close();

    return handle;
};
```

You would need to adapt the code somewhat, in order for it to work for you - for example, you'd have to replace `myBtn` with the actual ID of your submit button, replace the `#myForm` with the ID of your actual form, etc.

If you have multiple forms, you could expand this, to capture the inputs from all of them, but then you would have to have a single button responsible for all of the forms (which would be unusual, to say the least). Also, if you have different types of form elements within the form, you would need to modify the example, by adding additional checks and loops for checkboxes, radiobuttons, etc.

**EDIT** Corrected a serious mistake in the code, and added an actual downloading.

Comment: results.html has a table in it, with 5 cells, can you still work with that

Comment: Sure, see the updated code - a simple table-building  logic has been added. The table has three columns (#, question, answer). If you need more columns, you would add them to the `let html = ...` part. In that case, you would also need to expand the `let tempStr = ...` part, to account for the additional columns.